# Accessing entities via aggregate root: simple example?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Can you show simple example of accessing the contents of an entity in an aggregate via ita aggregate root? I am not clear on how you would represent the Aggregate permissions to reflect these concepts. tia.

Comment: zsharp - is there anything that you want clearing up in the answer I gave below?

Answer (score 9):

You typically would encapsulate this in commands that the Aggregate exposes on its contract.

For example, with an Order Aggregate, you might add OrderLines using data obtained from your GUI.

```cs
// This is the Order Aggregate Root
public class Order
{
    private readonly int id;
    private readonly Customer customer; // Customer is another Aggregate
    private readonly IList<OrderLine> orderLines;
    private readonly IOrderLineFactory orderLineFactory;

    public Order(int id, Customer customer, IOrderLineFactory orderLineFactory)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.orderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
        this.orderLineFactory = orderLineFactory;
    }

    public void AddOrderLine(Item item, int quantity)
    {
        OrderLine orderLine = orderLineFactory.Create(this, item, quantity);
        orderLines.Add(orderLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question but...In your model, if I wanted to update an OrderLine, what would that look like....should there be a public orderLines list? And then pass the order back to a repository to update the Order/Customer/OrderItems?

Comment: @Craig any luck on the above question? I am really struggling with exactly the same thing. How does one make updates on nested entities within a aggregate root ?

Comment: @Sudarshan All access should go through the aggregate root - so no, there shouldn't be a public order lines list. You'd need to expose a method on the aggregate root to allow this.

Comment: Would'nt this approach cause a bloat in the interface exposed by the AR? It Would need to expose the behavior of all its entities via its own interface. Also assume that orderline had a Set Of Tags which needed to be updated. Would we go along with something like order.changeTagTitle(orderLineId,tagId, "New title"); ?