# Domain Driven Design: Order and Order line Classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, domain-driven-design

We know in a Database Model, Order and Orderline are generally two separate tables. When modelling the Domain Driven Classes, should they be generally be 1 Denormalized Class or separate classes?

**One Domain Class:**

```
public class Order 
{
    public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderLineNumber { get; set;}
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; 

}
```

**Separated like Database:**

```
public class OrderHeader  
{
    public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderLineNumber { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLine{ get; set; }
}


public class OrderLine
{
    public int OrderLineNumber { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; 

    public virtual ICollection<OrderHeader> OrderHeader { get; set; }
}
```

[DDD - Aggregate Root - Example Order and OrderLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329322/ddd-aggregate-root-example-order-and-orderline)

Comment: This seems a better fit for SoftwareEngineering, questions asking about generality of design patterns and the latest fashion sense tend to be subjective

Comment: @TheGeneral when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to focus on the design and not worry too much about persistence from the get-go.  In terms of the `Order`/`OrderLine` example it is a rather well-known structure and represents a couple of design elements that are interesting.

When performing object modelling you most certainly don't need to *flatten* anything unless it really has to.  I take the order example slightly further and include any value objects that are only ever related to the aggregate root as nested classes in the root class, like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; }
    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; }

    private readonly List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

    public Order(Guid id, Guid customerId, DateTime dateRegistered)
    {
        Id = id;
        CustomerId = customerId;
        DateRegistered = dateRegistered;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems() => _items.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddItem(Guid productId, string description, decimal count, decimal unitPrice)
    {
        _items.Add(new Item(productId, description, count, unitPrice));
    }

    public class Item
    {
        // get-only properties
        internal Item(Guid productId, string description, decimal count, decimal unitPrice)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

There are variations but you should implement it in a way that you are comfortable with.  I prefer not to use aggregate instances when adding related objects such as the `Product` since that would mean my repository would need to somehow get to a `Product` when hydrating the `Order` instance.  One *could* have overloaded methods for `AddItem` where one takes the `productId` and the other a `Product` where the `product.Id` is used but I see little value in that.

The interesting thing about the `Order`->`Item` scenario is that the `OrderItem` table, in an entity-relationship model sense, is an *associative entity* (or link-table) between `Order` and `Product`.  However, we are all quite comfortable when dealing with this relationship and "*know*" that the items are related *closer* to the order and we model it as such.  The reason I mention this is that one runs in many such scenarios where the *side* you need to pick to create a one-to-many relationship is not quite a evident.

Comment: thanks! asked follow up question here, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/396190/domain-driven-design-is-orderline-detail-a-nested-class-of-order-header

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for an object-oriented design, you should not concern yourself too much with data. Objects should have *behavior*.

If the objects are supposed to have *behavior*, it becomes easier to decide what is an object and what isn't. Does the `OrderLine` have something to actually do? If not, then it shouldn't exist. "Doing" here means something that directly contributes to some business function, not storing and retrieving data.

Comment: Behaviour is, as you say, quite important and without any behaviour a model would be rather anemic.  That being said, an `Order` cannot behave as an order without at least *one* thing (`Product` / `Service`) being ordered.  This is probably even more reason to couple the item tightly with the order (using a nested class in my case) so that it is apparent that it exists to satisfy an invariant that makes an order an order.